# Formatting location of buttons within JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, format, joptionpane

Im trying to format the location of buttons within a JOptionPane. Right now they are side by side, but I would like to put them on top of each other.

I tried making a global configuration but it did not work. How would I achieve this?

```
Object[] options = { "Restart Game at Level 1",
                    "Restart and Increase Difficulty (Speed)",
                    "Change Game Map", "Exit Game" };
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(gamePanel,
                    "GAME OVER - YouHit a Wall and Died! ",
                    "Game Over!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[3]);
```

Comment: An option pane is a great utility component for when you can get by with using it exactly as it comes. For anything more complex, look to use a `JDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but I wouldn't recommend it since it makes assumptions of internal implementation of JOptionPane. There are 2 things to do:

1. Create a JOptionPane using directly a constructor to get a reference to it
2. Change the layout of inner component containing the options (which
   is on  position 1)

   ```
   JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("GAME OVER - YouHit a Wall and Died! ");
   op.setOptions(options );
   ((Container)op.getComponent(1)).setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
   JDialog dlg = op.createDialog("Game Over!");
   dlg.setVisible(true);
   ```